# Couldn`t find PlaceAutocompleteFragment

Tags: android

I used PlaceAutocompleteFragment in my Activity and it worked. Then I wanted to move this code to my Fragment and it stoped to work.

**Executing my fragment in MainActivity:**

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
```

**ForecastFragment:**

```
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_forecast, container, false);

        autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);
        AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
                .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_CITIES)
                .build();

        autocompleteFragment.setFilter(typeFilter); //here I have NullPointerException
        //...

        return v;
    }
}
```

I have NullPointerExceprion on **`autocompleteFragment.setFilter(typeFilter)`**

**fragment_forecast.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment" android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[Here is my project on GitHub](https://github.com/BirukovAleksandr48/TheWeather.git)

Comment: I haven't studied your code thoroughly but try to use `childFragmentManager`, like this `getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);`

Comment: @LieForBananas, it helped me! ty

Comment: No problem, happy coding!